# How do I successfully make an HTTP PUT request in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, put

I am on my 4th day in getting used to Vue CLI and am trying to make an HTTP put request, but really don't know where to start. I have it setup to where when a user clicks a like button on a specific product, it will add a like to the actual product, but I want it to save to my database. Any help would be much appreciated, but also know that I am still learning and quite new to this JavaScript Library. I am also using Vue Resource to make this PUT request.

When I click the like button, I can confirm that it adds a like to that specific product and displays on that specific products's amount of likes. Just have no idea how to properly send it to the database.

Here is my code for the PUT request. Do I need headers and

```
    methods: {
      updateLikes(product){
        //make a put request to the backend to update the amount of likes on
        //the specific product when the user click like button
        product.likes = product.likes + 1
        this.$http.put(`https://tap-on-it-exercise-backend.herokuapp.com/products/${product.likes}`, {
          //send updated likes for the product to the backend

        })
        //close the modal after user like
        this.modalShow = false
      console.log(product.likes);
    }
  }
```

update code:

```
methods: {
  updateLikes(product){

    let newProductLikes = product.likes + 1

    //make a put request to the backend to update the amount of likes on
    //the specific product when the user click like button

    console.log('new', newProductLikes);

    fetch(`https://tap-on-it-exercise-backend.herokuapp.com/products/${product.likes}`, {
      method: 'PUT',
      mode: "cors",
      cache: "no-cache",
      credentials: "same-origin",
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        // send updated like to the server
        likes: newProductLikes
      })
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: What result are you getting in the network tab in your browser's developer tools? a 200, a 404, etc? Is your server throwing any errors?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the browser's native [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) API.

```
fetch(`https://tap-on-it-exercise-backend.herokuapp.com/products/${product.likes}`, {
  method: 'PUT',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    // data you intend to send as JSON to the server
    whatever: 'ding!'
  })
})
```

Comment: `this.$http` is actually looking like a call to Vue Resource https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource

Comment: @MaciejKwas yeah, I noticed that. I'm quickly reviewing Vue Resource.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, i'm quite new to these PUT requests, so in the stringify section, I am putting this in:  product.likes = product.likes + 1. its then giving me an error saying: "Unexpected token, expected "," " on this period between product and likes. Im a little confused with the data flow i guess.

Comment: @TylerOreskey most likely you're using equals inside an object/hash/dictionary. `{whatever = 'ding'}` instead of the correct `{whatever: 'ding'}` syntax

Comment: I have that, and it does not make any changes to the db, im gonna update my code in my post if you're interested.

Comment: if this helps, here is a screenshot of one of the products from the api: https://imgur.com/a/c8uKxpO

Comment: Ultimate Solution. Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

In Vue Resource you can make a HTTP PUT request like below

```
this.$http.put('/someUrl', {your request body}).then(response => {
  this.product.likes = response.body.likes; // update your data from the response
}, error => {
   // error callback
});
```

You can look at the [Vue Resource docs](https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource/blob/develop/docs/http.md) for more detailed information.

Also I think you shouldn't be manually increase product likes, you can set it from your requests response if response includes updated product likes count, because maybe the product likes didn't update on the server.

Comment: This answer doesn't relate to the original question. If you want to comment or make suggestions, use the comments for that and please delete this question.

Comment: This is just a recommendation, and I can't make a comment because of my reputation number. I saw your answer and thought give more idea about the question, but sure I will edit my answer according to original question

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to make sure you can send the PUT request directly, without using Vue. You can do this using Curl or [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/).

Second, check the Network tab in your browser's developer tools (<kbd>F12</kbd>) when you send the request from Vue. Is the request sending properly? Is the server returning an error?

Next, check for CORS issues. There's a good chance your request is being denied because it is being sent from localhost to your server, and you haven't allowed the right CORS access.

Comment: Cors headers are there, and I can just re run my seeds and re push to heroku to reset the db